# magento2- Not able to get details of logged in customer.

Tags: magento2, customer

I have tried to obtain the logged in customer details by using all the below models. Nothing seems to work. Are  there any other ways to obtain the user data?

```
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $backendAuthSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $currentSession ,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
```

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if not working.

Comment: Will do.  I was Injecting the above three models the way you have said.  But not the  \Magento\Customer\Model\Session model itself.

Comment: Please upload your full code here.

Comment: It did not work.  Do I need to make any changes to app/etc/di.xml ?.  I am trying to render this in a PHTML

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` in your construct

```
protected $_session;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_session = $session;
    ...
}
```

Then add this below code in your function

```
if ($this->_session->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo $this->_session->getCustomer()->getId(); //Logged in customer id will display
    echo $this->_session->getCustomer()->getName(); //Logged in customer name will display
} else {
    echo "customer not logged in";
}
```